# strange issue with foundation 5 and links

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

this is really weird, some of my links cannot be clicked if and only if they are directly above a link button as used in foundation 5. It is hard to setup a page but try to put some "lorem ipsum" and combine the links so that will be directly above to the button-like link at the bottom, here is my code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMain" runat="server">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <h5 style="font-family:Verdana;">my lorem header.</h5>
            <p class="text-justify"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel natum etiam ex, eu aeque consequat mea. Duo rebum assum imperdiet et, etiam <a href="link1.aspx">abhorreant</a> philosophia id sit, per partem tacimates ad. Pri autem illum posse ex, cu <a href="link2.aspx">luptatum invenire</a> argumentum nec. Mentitum eleifend consetetur vix ei, usu alia omittam singulis ea. <a href="link3.aspx">Phaedrum patrioque eloquentiam et</a> sed.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="small-6 small-centered columns">
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <a class="button" href="/register.aspx">Registrer</a>
            </div>
        </div>        

    </div>


</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was my bad, I have added the code below between the two `<div>` inside the first `<div class="row">` and resolved this the issue by properly creating two rows as intended:

```
</div>   

<div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;">
```